# Sending messages across channels with Discord.js, yields 'undefined' error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm looking to create a 'say' command that allows me to directly message through the bot to a specific (or any, perhaps) channel. For beginner, and general testing purposes, my goal is to be able to use a standard `if(commandIs("command", message)` to directly message a channel in my test server, eventually evolving to all channels on a server.

Through my research I've stumbled upon the:

`var channel = client.servers.get("name", "My Server").defaultChannel;
client.sendMessage(channel, "Hello");`

code, which is exactly what I'm looking to do as a base since I can swap out the `.get("name", "My server")` for the actual channel ID, but doing this through a say-like command sets the `var` as a Channel class in my code, which doesn't support `.sendMessage()`

My current command code looks like:

```
if(commandIs("speak", message)){
    var chat = client.channels.get(18numberID);
        if(args.length === 1){
                message.channel.sendMessage('You did not say anything. Usage: `a~speak [message]`')
            } else {
                chat.sendMessage(args.join(" ").substring(8));
```

-but this brings up an `undefined`error on the `.sendMessage()`, which I figured it would. I've tried `message.chat.sendMessage()` and every other possible variation I could, even going to the bare two lines of code to test at `on.ready()`, but that continued to give me the same error. I've looked for a way around the `Channel` class created once the ID is found and that led me to the `TextChannel` and `GuildChannel` extensions, but I'm pretty sure there's an easier way around it considering all the code (even a couple examples here) do not contain all that extra information. I feel like I'm looking over something, or possibly complicating the code more than needed, but I'm not sure.

Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** It seems I was right and I looked over a few key points, specifically the channelID not having quotes around it to be a string. Tried the command alone and everything went great; tweaked the main code and it all worked out.

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't return a TextChannel.. are you sure its a TextChannel? Maybe there is a (security?) limitation on the client or something. Perhaps you should try asking on the discord.js server Discord.js Official#222078108977594368

Comment: I've been curious about that myself. I've tried every coding loophole I could figure or find as a beginner and nothing seemed to work. I'll make sure to contact the official Discord.js server and see what they think about it.

Comment: what is your djs version?

Comment: 11.0. As for the issue, I asked the discord.js official server and they did a great job of helping me out. The issue was around `.get` not working correctly because my ID wasn't a string. I used quotes around the channel ID and it didn't seem to work, so I rewrote the code from scratch in a testbot and everything happened to work out fine. Did the same in the main bot and everything clicked into place.

Comment: `defaultChannel` was deprecated.

Comment: `.sendMessage()` is also deprecated, use `.send()` instead

Comment: `client.servers` is also deprecated. If you're using Discord.js use http://discord.js.org for the docs.
it's client.guilds now

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I just have to outline a few things that no longer work in the **Discord.JS** library (Thanks for the heads-up Ty Q.!)

First of all, `.sendMessage()` has been deprecated, and will more than likely not work at all anymore / soon. The working equivalent of this is `.send()` - which is simpler, and is an easy change to make.

Second: `.defaultChannel` is unfortunately no longer a thing. We will have to be more specific when we want to send a message.

I'm not great at talking about these kinds of issues, so if anyone else wants to pick it up, please do.

---

Alright, let's let your command be set out like this:`a~speak [ChannelID] <Message>`

Let's say we use this command: `a~speak 12345689 I has a bucket`

What we want to do is find out whether we can find the channel with the ID, and if we can, send the message to it.

To do that, I think we should see if we can use the `client.channels.find("id", ID)` function.

---

### Let's Start by Setting Up Our Command

```
if(commandIs("speak", message)){
    args = args.shift();
    /* ["a~speak", "CHANNELID", "I", "has", "a", "bucket"]
    BECOMES
    ["123456789", "I", "has", "a", "bucket"]
    args [0]      [1]   [2]   [3]     [4]*/


    let chan = client.channels.find("id", args[0]); // Find the channel ID "123456789"
    if(chan) { // Check if that channel exists
        chan.send(args.shift().join(" "));
    } else {
        message.channel.send(args.join(" "));
    }
}
```

---

### Let's Follow That Command

If we type in `a~speak 12345689 I has a bucket`, our bot will look for a channel that *it has access to* with the id "123456789".

---

#### If your bot found the channel with the id "123456789":

`chan.send(args.shift().join(" "));`

We defined earlier that `chan = args[0]` - which would be "123456789", and we don't want to send that in the message, so we use `args.shift()` - this removes the first argument from the rest, leaving us with `["I", "has", "a", "bucket"]`.

After that, we use `.join(" ")` - this connects `["I", "has", "a", "bucket"]` with spaces to form `I has a bucket`.

We then simply send that message to the channel we defined, with `chan.send()`.

---

#### If your bot did *not* find the channel with the id "12456789"

`message.channel.send(args.join(" "));`

This one's a bit different in a few ways, first of all, we forget about the `chan` variable, because we couldn't find that channel. If we know this, we can deduce that the user may have instead said something like `a~speak I has a bucket` - without the ID altogether.

Knowing that, we (unlike before), *don't* want to `args.shift()` - we would remove the "I" bit! Instead, we just want to `args.join(" ")` to once again join the words together into a sentence, then send it away with `message.channel.send()` - which just sends it in the server it got the message from.

---

#### If you need any more help, just comment with your Discord name, and I'll be happy to give you a little push in the right direction.

### Sources of Information:

Some good places to look for help on these kinds of topics (Discord.JS), are the [Official Discord.JS Server](https://discord.gg/bRCvFy9) and [AnIdiotsGuide](https://anidiotsguide.gitbooks.io/discord-js-bot-guide/). Both of which will be able to solve your problems.

Comment: TL;DR: I think your problem is `var chat = client.channels.get(18numberID);` - I think you might have to use `var chat = client.channels.find("id", 18numberID);`.

Comment: I think you guys are ignoring the fact that OP is attempting to use deprecated code like `.sendMessage()` and `.defaultChannel`. if he has up-to-date Discord.js this will create errors. Also, I'm not sure the Discord API even still supports the versions of D.js that actually support these commands.

Comment: Ah, yes. I've removed the `Message` part of `.sendMessage()` out of habit, but I forgot to explain it's importance. I'll edit the post.

Comment: I think OP is using http://discordjs.readthedocs.io because all of his code is deprecated. I made the same mistake at first. Now I'm fairly decent at making bots. But, you have to use http://discord.js.org for the docs.

Comment: Me too. I actually prefer to use https://anidiotsguide.gitbooks.io/discord-js-bot-guide/ - I find it simpler to follow, and the examples really helped me out in the beginning. So there's 2 new sources of information packed full of usefulness.

Comment: Yeah, antidots guide is amazing. Also, SO isn't the best place for this kind of stuff. He should join the Discord.js Discord Server. There are plenty more people to help him out there. Here, there's basically just you, I, and a few others.

Comment: Editted the above post with a permalink to the Discord.JS chat.