# Discord.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined - channel.id

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeerror, discord, discord.js

(Working in discord.js Javascript)

I'm trying to make it so that users can only use commands in my #commands channel. I have this code at the beginning of the command.

```
  if (msg === prefix + 'DAILY') {

   if (msg.channel.id === '29124657224757826') {
```

The daily command worked perfectly before trying to make it only work in one channel.
This is the error message I get with the second line included:

```
  if (msg.channel.id === '394615572257570826') {
                    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

I believe I just need a channel.id variable, so how would I set it up? If that's not the fix, then what is? Thanks in advance.

Comment: your msg variable seems to be a string, maybe `Message.content`, not the Message object

Comment: As @MichelFeldheim said you need to use `msg.content` instead of just `msg`. This may have somehow still worked but screwed with the code and either way its better practice that way.

Answer (score 0):

like a comment said, the first line in the command handler needs to be msg.content instead of just message. Another problem is that msg is not defined. I bet it's because your command handler is not msg but is something else like message. Based off another similar problem that is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081155/sending-messages-across-channels-with-discord-js-yields-undefined-error)

what you would want to do is to find the channel using msg.guild.channels.find(). The question I have is what are you trying to do after line 2 where you are looking for the channel to match the id which may give you a better understanding